# Windows Identity Foundation with Claims based Authentication and Multiple Roles

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, wif, claims-based-identity

We are implementing a Secure Token Service (STS) which uses Windows Identity Foundation to provide Claims based authentication and authorisation.

My question is really about best practices and how we should handle multiple roles for a given identity.

When creating claims for a user after they have successfully logged in, we need to be able to add the roles that the user is a member of to the claims before returning to the Relying Party.

The Claim object does not accept a collection of strings so I'm wondering how this should be done. I can think of two ways:

1. I can add multiple Claims of type ClaimTypes.Role with different values and these can be read on the other side (I have tested and this seems to work without any errors)
2. I could also put the roles into a single claim and delimit them by ; or something like that.

My question is really about which of the above is better, or am I missing something better? Neither solution is perfect as it will require parsing on the other side.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ADFS as the STS, it inserts multiple roles into the claim

e.g.

- ...claims/role  Editor
- ...claims/role  Approver

etc.

The advantage of this is that WIF can then use the standard IsInRole constructs etc.

Comment: Thanks. We are using our own form of Authentication but if this is the way ADFS handles it then we can do the same.